# ObjectMapper Nested(Triple) Dictionaries

Tags: swift, xcode, objectmapper

Nested Json Package Below

### The issue is that it's converting json dictionary objects into strings, and not it's proper value. I don't understand how to grab the mvc value as an int, the exhaustion as an array.

[image]

Looking to understand how work with nest

```
{
        "id": 16,
        "user_id": 6,
        "name": 4,
        "med_gastro": "{'left': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}, 'right': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}}",
        "lat_gastro": "{'left': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}, 'right': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}}",
        "tib_anterior": "{'left': {'mvc': '13816.0', 'effeciency_score': 20.804231942965192, 'exhaustion': {'maxEffeciency': 10.16597510373444, 'subMaxEffeciency': 3.2009484291641965, 'minEffeciency': 86.63307646710136}, 'effeciency': 20.804231942965192}, 'right': {'mvc': '13816.0', 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}}",
        "peroneals": "{'left': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}, 'right': {'mvc': 0, 'effeciency_score': 0, 'exhaustion': [0, 0, 0]}}"
}
```

Coded Object

```
import Foundation 
import ObjectMapper


class PlayerProfile : NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable{

    var id : Int?
    var latGastro : String?
    var medGastro : String?
    var name : Int?
    var peroneals : String?
    var tibAnterior : String?
    var userId : Int?


    class func newInstance(map: Map) -> Mappable?{
        return PlayerProfile()
    }
    required init?(map: Map){}
    private override init(){}

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        id <- map["id"]
        latGastro <- map["lat_gastro"]
        medGastro <- map["med_gastro"]
        name <- map["name"]
        peroneals <- map["peroneals"]
        tibAnterior <- map["tib_anterior"]
        userId <- map["user_id"]

    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't this because they contain single quotes around the keys instead of double quotes?  `"{'left': {'mvc': 0,...` isn't proper json. Where did you get this so called json from? Anyway, you probably need to handle this manually, perhaps do a search and replace from single to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Decodable protocol you can manually decode your dictionary strings once you have fixed them.

As far as I can see all of them have the same structure so we only need to define one set of structs for all

```
struct DictionaryData: Codable {
    let itemLeft: Item
    let itemRight: Item?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemLeft = "left"
        case itemRight = "right"
    }
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let mvc, effeciencyScore: Int
    let exhaustion: [Int]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mvc
        case effeciencyScore = "effeciency_score"
        case exhaustion
    }
}
```

First we need to fix the string (assuming we have PlayerProfile object but this could of course be done inside the class) and then the string can be decoded.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let medGastro = playerProfile.medGastro, let data = medGastro.data(using: .utf8) { 
    let fixedString = medGastro.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")
    do {
        let jsonDict = try decoder.decode(DictionaryData.self, from: data)
        // Do something with jsonDict 
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and the same for the other fields, of course since this is the same for all fields you could put it in a function like

```
func parseString(_ string: String?) throws -> DictionaryData
```